# Titanium HTML Scrape

Tags: titanium

I could not be any more brand-spanking new to Titanium, so even finding the right search terms is a chore, but I need to prototype a means of loading external content into a mobile app. Lots of random poking around has yielded the `url` configuration property of the `createWebView()` method, but there's a twist (didn't you know there would be?). Now I need to extract only a particular DOM node (the `div` with an `id` value of `content`) and display only that content.

As best I can tell, it looks like the Kitchen Sink app's "XHR to Filesystem" demo looks like the right way to go, but I don't want to spin my wheels. Can anyone confirm whether I'm on the right track?

As a side question that I (admittedly) haven't researched much yet is whether I can load jQuery into my Titanium app and use it to extract the `#content` DOM from everything else.

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are on the right track with using the httpClient, you can also load up jQuery, but i think that it might be overkill if you are just trying to pull some content from XML

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Remote+Data

Comment: Thanks. I've actually read that page, but it appears to be API-specific. In this case, I need to scrape some HTML. I've been trying to use Titanium's YQL API, but no results are being returned at the moment.

Comment: Actually, I asked a more specific follow up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069598/yql-select-from-xml. That may be the place to start. Thank you.