# YQL select from xml

Tags: xml, xpath, yql

I'm using the YQL console to run the following query:

```
 select * 
   from xml 
  where url="http://www.inova.org/patient-and-visitor-information/facilities/inova-fair-oaks-hospital/plan-your-visit/index.jsp" 
        and itemPath="html.body.form"
```

No results are returned. I've also tried using `xpath` and `css` just for grins, but I get no results. If I remove the second filter, I get the page markup. Am I doing something wrong? It's an XHTML page (according to the doctype), so `select * from html` didn't work.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've updated my query syntax to the one query that seems to at least return results, but I need to dive deeper. What I really need to get to is something like this:

```
 select * 
   from xml 
  where url="http://www.inova.org/patient-and-visitor-information/facilities/inova-fair-oaks-hospital/plan-your-visit/index.jsp" 
        and itemPath="html.body.form.div#wrapper.div#page.div#content"
```

Unfortunately, that syntax for accessing a specific div by id doesn't work and I haven't found any way of reaching that target div (the one with `id="content"`) that returns any results at all.

**UPDATE**

I've stumbled, and I do mean *stumbled* onto a YQL query that works (for the moment, let's disregard just how brittle it is):

```
 select * 
   from xml 
  where url="http://www.inova.org/patient-and-visitor-information/facilities/inova-fair-oaks-hospital/plan-your-visit/index.jsp" 
        and itemPath="html.body.form.div.1.div.4.div.2"
```

Any suggestions for a way to make it less brittle (and ideally bulletproof) would be really, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may have to do with they way the xhtml is written and not the actual YQL statement.

Firefox throws this error when trying to access the YQL statement direct:

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location:http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inova.org%2Fpatient-and-visitor-information%2Ffacilities%2Finova-fair-oaks-hospital%2Fplan-your-visit%2Findex.jsp%27
Line Number 307, Column 12:

Fairfax, VA&nbsp; 22033<br/>
-----------^
```

If you are using jQuery you can get around it with something along these lines:

```js
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'xml',
    url : 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inova.org%2Fpatient-and-visitor-information%2Ffacilities%2Finova-fair-oaks-hospital%2Fplan-your-visit%2Findex.jsp%22',
    success : function(xhtml) {
        //find all nodes
        $(xhtml).find('h1').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).html())
        });

        //target specific node
        console.log($('#content').html())
    }
})
```

Comment: You're right. I've gone through many, many syntax iterations and I pasted one that wasn't exactly correct. I've corrected it to one that does work (read: returns results), but I need to dive a few layers deeper. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Oh, nm. I just reread your answer and this time it actually clicked. I'll look at the page, but I think YQL cleans that stuff up which might explain why the modified query above works to at least some level.

Comment: That's basically the way to traverse the JSON response. You would still need outside coding to get all the h1 nodes. Even with the new way, the browser still outputs xml parsing errors.

Comment: If you really want to fix the page up, create an entity in the DTD for &nbsp; like <!ENTITY nbsp " "> and then see if you can use itemPath (or fix any new errors parse errors that may pop up).

Comment: Hmmm. I was hoping I could get YQL to get me where I needed to be in the markup so I could just drop that markup somewhere else. See above for an itemPath that does just that (albeit in a manner that is fragile as hell).

Comment: What are your options? Are you looking to just use the rest query as the "be and end all" instead of something like the jQuery example? It's a lot more bulletproof to use $('#content').html() then the crazy itemPath option that could easily be broken.

Comment: This is part of a Titanium app. My intent is to pull a specific piece of content using YQL and drop it into a mobile view fully marked up. Essentially, I was hoping for a targeted screen scrape. :-)

Comment: Gotcha. Well until the page gets cleaned up, it looks like you might have to keep using the shaky bacon way (and possibly have to adjust again if the page changes in anyway). :-(

Comment: That would be unfortunate at best and dangerous at worst. I'll search for improvements once I have everything actually functional. :-) Thanks for your help.